# PHP gdrive upload file

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

There is no error. Why is not the file sent?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
         try{       
    require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();

    $oauth_credentials = './vendor/test.json';


    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');


    $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => 'photo.png'));


    $content = file_get_contents('./vendor/plik.png');
    $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
        'data' => $content,
        'mimeType' => 'image/png',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'fields' => 'id'));
    printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);

    }catch(Exception  $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't go somewhere else to figure out what you're asking. All relevant code must be here, in the question itself. See [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your post to include the minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate the issue. You'll also want to include a tag for the language you're using to write your code, as clearly that would be relevant. (Yes, I see PHP in the title, but it should be in a tag as well for use by future readers here when searching.)

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a service account.   A service account is not you.  Files uploaded using a service account will be uploaded to the service accounts google drive account.

Tips for using service accounts with google drive:

1. No there is no web view for the service accounts files.
2. Do a file.list to see if the file was in fact uploaded to your service account.
3. share a directory on your personal google drive account and have the service account upload to that.  Remember to grant yourself permissions to the file.

Comment: Ok, file display works.. But... How to share this folder? To be seen here https://drive.google.com/drive